# QGIS Plugins window size too small

Tags: plugins, size

When I open the batch heatmap plugin within QGIS, the information in the dialog box is overlapping and doesn't fit the window. Even if I increase the size of the dialog box. It makes it pretty much impossible to use.
[image]